Convert State Int to Int
I am trying to implement a counter and I'd like to convert something of type State Int to Int, so I can add it to a variable. Can somebody help me develop an auxiliary function to perform this cast?
I have been stuck on this for a while now, because I am not very used to working with monad State.

Run it with e.g. evalState. Or are you just looking for >>= and do-notation? Anyway, State Int is not a type, it has kind Type -> Type.

The name State a is a bit misleading imho, State a does not specify the system at a certain state, it describes changing a state, so you need to put in some initial state first.

I strongly suspect you do not want to do what you say you want to do. Indeed, you almost certainly want the exact opposite: rather than extracting an Int from your State Int _, you probably ought to be looking into how to convert the function that consumes the current counter from an Int -> _ into a State Int Int -> _ (which can then be applied to get :: State Int Int). Depending on the return type of this function, you will want to look at fmap or (>>=).

Use execState to run the stateful action and obtain the final state:
execState :: State s a -> s -> s


For example, incByOne increments the counter by one:
incByOne :: State Int ()
incByOne = modify (+1)

Then, if you use the execState monad runner with the initial state of 7:
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let initialCount = 7
  let count = execState incByOne initialCount
  print count

It will print 8

My problem is, how do I concatenate it with a string. For example, how can I do "a" ++ (show count)?

Once you have count, just as you are saying: "a" ++ show count

The name State is a bit misleading: it is not the state of a certain system: a State s a essentially is a function that takes in a state (of type s) and produces a new (possibly different) state and an output value (of type a). You can then combine two such State s a and State s b where you first change the state by the first one and then pass this to the next one.
But essential is, State s a does not contain a state: you have to put in an initial state first. For example 0, with:
execState myState 0
But if you do this multiple times, you each time get the same answer, since you put in the same initial state, and since there is no non-determinism, it will thus each time produce the same result.
Very likely execState is not really what you are looking for: State Int is not some "magic database" that spans over several runs of that State, it is a database for as long as you are evaluating a stream of State s a items.
